# How do I figure out what is preventing a bind mount from unmounting?

Tags: mount, lsof, fuser

I have a problem with a mountpoint being too busy to unmount. Normally, lsof or fuser would tell me what process is using it, but this is a bind mount, so lsof and fuser show what is using both the original mountpoint, and the bind mountpoint.

Ex:

Mount the filesystems:

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/mount /mnt/bind
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/mount
$ sudo mount -o bind /mnt/mount /mnt/bind
```

Start a process that keeps /mnt/mount too busy to unmount

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/mount/testfile bs=1 oflag=dsync
```

Check what fuser says

```
$ sudo fuser -m /mnt/mount
/mnt/mount:           4022
$ sudo fuser -m /mnt/bind
/mnt/bind:            4022
```

Check what lsof says

```
$ sudo lsof +D /mnt/mount
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
dd      4022 root    1w   REG   8,17    28545   12 /mnt/mount/testfile

$ sudo lsof +D /mnt/bind
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
dd      4022 root    1w   REG   8,17    40682   12 /mnt/bind/testfile
```

Try to unmount both

```
$ sudo umount -v *
umount: /mnt/bind (/mnt/mount) unmounted
umount: /mnt/mount: target is busy
```

If you follow the same steps, but tell dd to write the file to /mnt/bind/testfile instead, unmounting /mnt/mount will be successful, but unmounting /mnt/bind will fail.

Clearly it makes a difference which mountpoint the process (dd in this case) is using, but lsof and fuser do not differentiate. Is there something that does?

Comment: Did you try `lsof -pn | grep /mnt/bind` and `lsof -pn | grep /mnt/mount` ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to wurtel, this became apparent:

While both fuser and lsof as used in my question both show the same process using both mountpoints, after either of those commands tell you the PID, running:

```
lsof -p $PID
```

does reveal exactly which mountpoint is being used. A bit of grepping and you're set.

Comment: @mikeserv: Maybe I'm using it wrong, but `-M` does not appear to help. Do you have an example of how to use it to tell if a process is writing to /mnt/mount or /mnt/bind?

Comment: thats cause its the wrong one - got it mixed up with `-m`. `-M` only works if the named file arg is a mountpoint but behaves identically otherwise - only listing process using that specific arg. `-m`, on the other hand, lists all process using any file on a mounted filesystem. With `-v` it prints to stderr a `ps` like list of things they might be doing with the files - `m` specifies a mount point. So try `fuser -v /mnt/point` and `fuser -vm /mnt/point` and hopefully youll see what i mean.

Comment: But you know what - i dont think that does what youre asking anyway. `lsof` definitely does, of course. w/ `fuser` maybe like `fuser -vMm $(findmnt -UnRloTARGET /mnt/point)` - but there `findmnt` does moat of the work anyway.

Comment: Neither `fuser -v`, `fuser -vm`, or `fuser -vMm $(findmnt -UnRloTARGET /mnt/point)` appear to be able to tell the difference between dd writing to /mnt/mount and dd writing to /mnt/bind. So far, the only way that works seems to be `lsof -p`

Comment: yeah - typically `lsof` will have the leg-up there - it's a more complicated tool. I'm sure what the difference is between your mnts bind and mnt - you haven't said - but I 'm not surprised if `lsof` provides more information.