# Docker filesystem has no open files but cannot unmount

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, mount, docker

I have an ext4 filesystem mounted on `/var/lib/docker`, using Ubuntu 14.04.

I ran `umount /var/lib/docker` and got:

```
umount: /var/lib/docker: device is busy.
```

I had already shut down docker with `service docker stop` and `ps aux` showed no processes.

The strange thing is that both `fuser -M /var/lib/docker` and `lsof +f -- /var/lib/docker` show no processes with files open.

This doesn't happen on 40+ other servers with same setup, and I have just noticed this.

A reboot fixed this - curious if anyone has some idea what's going on, or any other ways to investigate if it recurs.

- Docker (1.11.2) had been using aufs as the overlay filesystem for its containers, on top of this FS - but all containers and Docker processes were killed before the `umount`.
- Kernel details: `Linux node05 4.4.0-38-generic #57~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 17:20:43 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Possibly related questions:

- [Can't unmount a loop filesystem but no open files](https://serverfault.com/questions/58991/cant-unmount-a-loop-backed-file-but-theres-no-open-files)
- [What's preventing unmount of a bind mount?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170506/how-do-i-figure-out-what-is-preventing-a-bind-mount-from-unmounting?rq=1)

#### UPDATE - recurrence on another server

This recurred on a different server with very similar configuration, in same situation - have shut down docker, and can't `umount /var/lib/docker` because it's "busy".

As before, `fuser` and `lsof` show no processes with files open on the docker FS.

`mount | grep aufs` showed no aufs filesystems

`df -h| grep docker` showed two Docker managed filesystems mounted underneath the /var/lib/docker directory (`lsof` doesn't show these, it seems).

However, unmounting these two filesystems didn't help with this problem.

#### Workaround

The only workaround remains to edit `/etc/fstab` to temporarily comment out the `/var/lib/docker` filesystem, then reboot the server so `/var/lib/docker` is not mounted.

Comment: are any of the aufs overlays still mounted after docker exits?  maybe try `mount | grep aufs`

Comment: There were no aufs filesystems mounted under `/var/lib/docker` (as there are normally), so it seems like they were unmounted by the `service docker stop`.  This is based on a `df` as root (not sure why `mount` doesn't show these nested mounts).